# Pandas resample MultiIndex dataframe with forward fill

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to resample a MultiIndex dataframe to a less granular frequency (daily to month end) by taking the last valid daily observation in every month.

For example, given the dataframe below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [pd.to_datetime('2012-03-29')]*4 
                   + [pd.to_datetime('2012-03-30')]*4 
                   + [pd.to_datetime('2012-04-01')]*4, 
                   'groups':[1,2,3,4]*3, 
                   'values':np.random.normal(size=12)})
df = df.set_index(['date', 'groups'])


                      values
date        groups  
2012-03-29     1    0.013681
               2    0.359522
               3    -0.525454
               4    -0.282541
2012-03-30     1    0.155501
               2    -1.053596
               3    0.003049
               4    -0.165875
2012-04-01     1    -0.049135
               2    2.701785
               3    2.240875
               4    0.057297
```

The desired final dataframe is:

```
                      values
date        groups  
2012-03-31     1    0.155501
               2    -1.053596
               3    0.003049
               4    -0.165875
```

In a regular dataframe (with single index), the desired output can be achieved with df.asfreq('M', method='ffill') as shown below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [pd.to_datetime('2012-03-29')] + pd.date_range('2012-04-01', '2012-04-04').to_list(), 
                   'values':np.random.normal(size=5)})
df = df.set_index('date')
df_monthly = df.asfreq('M', method='ffill')

Where df is: 
 
             values
date    
2012-03-29  1.988554
2012-04-01  -1.054163
2012-04-02  -1.112537
2012-04-03  0.224515
2012-04-04  0.152175

and df_monthly is: 

             values
date    
2012-03-31  1.988554
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df_monthly = df.reset_index(level=1).groupby('groups')[['values']].apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('M', method='ffill')).swaplevel(1,0)
print (df_monthly)
                     values
date       groups          
2012-03-31 1      -2.951662
           2      -1.495653
           3      -0.948413
           4       0.066219
```